# Convergence to normal distribution in total variation distance

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Let $X_i$ be independent, identically distributed random variables with a uniform distribution on $\{M+1,...,2M\}$ (say), where $M$ is a positive integer. What would be a *lower* bound for how rapidly $X = \sum_{i=1}^k X_i$ converges (as $k$ grows) to a normal distribution *in total variation distance* (or $l^1$ norm, which amounts to the same thing)? I imagine convergence eventually becomes exponential, but only for $k\gg \log M$ or so, no?

(As stated, this should be an easy and standard combinatorial problem. Of course I'd be especially interested in an answer that generalizes well to other discrete distributions.)

Comment: What is this X?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Just added that, thanks

Comment: Answer to next objection: I really mean "the normal distribution discretized in some obvious way" (for instance, the values of an appropriately scaled Gaussian at the integers).

Comment: If the difference of distributions of $X$ and the approximating Gaussian has (uniformly) finitely many sign changes, then for $k=1000$ you already have small total variation for all $M$, by usual CLT. Do you expect this to be not the case?

Comment: Well, "small" there would be about $1/\sqrt{k}$, no? Can one show one can't do much better for smallish $k$? (I'd expect convergence becomes much faster once $k$ gets to be of size $\log M$ or so.)

Comment: The law of $X$ is discrete, whereas the approximating normal law is absolutely continuous, so the total variation distance is $1$... So you should edit your question and precise what is the discretisation used (the speed of convergence may depend on this choice).

Comment: Of course, $X$ doesn't converge at all, what you probably had in mind is the rv $(X-kEX_1)/(\sqrt{k}\sigma_{X_1})$.

Comment: As I said, I really mean the Gaussian, normalized essentially as @ChristianRemling said, evaluated at the integers.